# Dangling reference in range loops

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

There is the following piece of code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A
{
public:
    auto foo()
    {
        //std::vector<int> vec;
        return std::vector<int>{} ;
    }
};

auto bar()
{
    return A();
}
int main() {
    for(auto && el : bar().foo())
    {

    }
}
```

In my point  of view the code above has UB due to dangling reference? Is this correct?
I have the impression that in the code above the follwing statement applies

> In general, the lifetime of a temporary cannot be further extended by
> "passing it on": a second reference, initialized from the reference
> variable or data member to which the temporary was bound, does not
> affect its lifetime.

However the sanitiser does not detect this issue

Moreover cppreference refers the following

> If range-expression returns a temporary, its lifetime is extended
> until the end of the loop, as indicated by binding to the forwarding
> reference __range. Lifetimes of all temporaries within
> range-expression are not (until C++23) extended if they would
> otherwise be destroyed at the end of range-expression (since C++23).

Have a look in the following [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/M47fGn6W8)

Comment: Because both functions return their objects *by value* there are no dangling references.

Comment: This should be fine. `el` is bound to the temporary object returned by `foo()`.

Comment: This is in effect a duplicate as marked, but I don't think the question that was *intended* to be asked is a duplicate.

Comment: // if foo() returns by value
for (auto& x : foo().items()) { /* .. */ } // until C++23 undefined behavior , What in cpp reference is used as example . If I changed  the example above to const & then still continues to be ok?

Comment: @getsoubl It's still UB until C++23.

Comment: @songyuanyao ,  you mean my demo is UB? But then sanitizer why does not detect it

Comment: @getsoubl No, your code is different. I suppose the code intended by cppreference.com should be sth like https://godbolt.org/z/T8bre5e6W. The point is that the lifetime of temporary returned by `bar()` won't be extened until C++23 which might cause issues (like binding reference to data member of the temporary).